# Vuejs form needs refresh in order to let the router.push work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

so I have a website that allows you to send a submission; it's a Laravel/Vuejs application . My issue is that if I go to my form and fill everything in and submit my form; my loader is stuck and my router.push doesnt push to the location I want it to go. it keeps getting stuck. Although the collection is saved in the database and previewed on the list.

BUT once I manually refresh my page, the form submits, my router.push works and the loader is not stuck. And I can't figure out why this happens.

I get an error on my `this.addItemToCollection(response.data)`

error:  http://prntscr.com/rfpsez

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP2nl.jpg

**Form.vue**

```
<template>
      <form class="uk-form-horizontal"
              @keydown="form.errors.clear( $event.target.name )">

                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-body">
                    <h3 class="uk-card-title">Submission</h3>

                <default-text-input v-model="form.distillery"
                          :name="'distillery'"
                          :label="'Distillery'"
                          required />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.age"
                          :name="'age'"
                          :label="'Age'"
                           />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.type"
                          :name="'type'"
                          :label="'Type'"
                          required />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.volume"
                          :name="'volume'"
                          :label="'Volume'"
                          required /> 

                <default-text-input v-model="form.name"
                          :name="'name'"
                          :label="'Name'"
                          required />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.size"
                          :name="'size'"
                          :label="'Size'"
                          />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.strength"
                          :name="'strength'"
                          :label="'Strength'"
                          required />

                <default-text-input v-model="form.reserve_price"
                          :name="'reserve_price'"
                          :label="'Reserve Price'"
                          required />

        <div class="uk-margin-top uk-text-right">
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-text">
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-margin-left"
            @click.prevent="handleSubmit()">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>

            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Form from '@/forms/form'
  import { mapState, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'
  import TrumbowygConfig from '@/mixins/trumbowyg-config'
  import toolbarCaptions from '@/mixins/toolbar-captions'
  import router from '@/router/index'
  import { SubmissionFieldset } from '@/environments/members/modules/my-submissions/support/submission-fieldsets'


export default {

  name: 'members-my-submission-form',

  mixins: [ TrumbowygConfig, toolbarCaptions ],

  data () {
    return {

      form: new Form(SubmissionFieldset()),

      loadingSubmission: false

    }
  },

  created () {
      this.loadData()
  },

  // Watch the loader
  watch: {
      loadingSubmission () { this.checkLoading() },
    },

  computed: {
    // set cpation
        caption () {
          'New submission'
        },


      ...mapState({
        module: state => state.module
      }),


      /**
       * Convenient access to the submissions state.
       */
      ...mapState('membersSubmissions', {
        apiResource: state => state.endpoint,
        notifications: state => state.collection.settings,
        dataLoaded: state => state.dataLoaded
      }),

      /**
       * indicates the form method should be spoofed to post.
       */
      method () {
        return 'post'
      },


      /**
       * Api endpoint.
       */
      endpoint () {
        return this.apiResource
      }

  },

  methods : {

      ...mapActions('membersSubmissions', {
        loadSubmission: 'loadCollection'
      }),

      ...mapMutations('membersSubmissions', {
        setDataLoaded: 'setDataLoaded',
        addItemToCollection: 'pushItem',
        replaceItemInCollection: 'replaceItem',
      }),

        /**
       * Load data for this view.
       */
      loadData () {
          this.setLayoutProperties()
      },

      /**
       * Submit the form.
       */
      handleSubmit () {

         // Initiaze the loader
          this.$store.commit( 'setLoading', true )

          // submit the form
          this.form.submit(this.method, this.endpoint).then(response => {

            // create a new submission
            this.addItemToCollection(response.data)

            // Get back to the list page.
           router.push({ name: 'my-submissions.collection' })

           // de-activate the loader
           this.$store.commit( 'setLoading', false )

          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
        },


            /**
             * Set layout properties for this view.
             */
            setLayoutProperties () {
                // Store the right items for the toolbar in the store.
                this.$store.commit( 'setLayout', {
                    caption: this.caption,
                    tools: [ 'go-back' ]
                })
            },



      checkLoading () {
        let loading = this.loadingSubmission

        this.$store.commit( 'setLoading', loading )
        this.ready = ! loading
      },

  }

}
</script>
```

**Router.js:**

```
 export default [
    {
        path: "/members/my-submissions/",
        component: (resolve) => require([ "./Base" ], m => resolve(m.default)),
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                name: "my-submissions.collection",
                component: (resolve) => require([ "./components/List" ], m => resolve(m.default))
            },
            {
                path: "create",
                name: "submission.new",
                component: (resolve) => require(["./components/Form"], m => resolve(m.default))
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

**Collection-mutation.js**

```
     /**
     * Push new item to the collection.
     */
    pushItem (state, payload) {
        state.collection.push(payload)
    },
```

Comment: have you tried using `this.$router.push` instead of `router.push`

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw yes, same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, apparently the data object was an object in an object, and the state.push expected an array while it gave an object. and since the refresh caused it to lose its data; the object was lost and turned in an empty array. so thats why it worked after the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Nested paths that start with root `/` are treated as root paths. So when you are on `/members/my-submissions/`, for Vue router, it is as if you are on root path `/` since `/` matches `/members/my-submissions/` as well as `/members/my-submissions/create` and thus no navigation happens.

To fix this, leave your first nested path empty, like:

```
{
    // This should be EMPTY.
    path: "",
    name: "my-submissions.collection",
    component: (resolve) => 
        require([ "./components/List" ], m => resolve(m.default))
}
```

Read more about this at: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: My `path:` is now empty like you described, yet the same thing still happens. everytime there is a refresh it works. If I manually type the route my-submissions/create (the page reloads) and it works. but when I click on my button (new submission) I won't get redirected after I click on save.

Comment: @Wesley, does address bar in the browser update when you click the button? Can you post a complete example with component templates?

Comment: Actually, the problem is not in my vue router, my ```this.addItemToCollection(response.data)
``` gives an error before the hard refresh:http://prntscr.com/rfpsez